# Rules for beta conversion passing abstraction as parameter

Tags: lambda-calculus

Can you tell me why the following reduction is true?

$$
(\lambda x.yx)(\lambda y.xy)=yx
$$

I'm not quite sure about the rules to follow when abstraction $(\lambda y.xy)$ is applied to $(\lambda x.yx)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Thanks. Edited the question providing more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because

$$
\lambda y.xy \to_\eta x
$$

So rightly

$$
y(\lambda y.xy)=yx
$$

Comment: Your question's title only refers to $\beta$-reduction, for which $\lambda y. xy$ cannot be reduced. If you also consider $\eta$-reduction, you should say that clearly.

Answer (score 2):

The rule for $\beta$-reduction is unique and always the same:
$$
(\lambda x. M)N \to_\beta M[N/x]
$$
where $M[N/x]$ is the term obtained from $M$ by substituting $N$ for each free occurrence of the variable $x$ in $M$.

In your example, $M = yx$ and $N = \lambda y. xy$, hence $M[N/x] = y(\lambda y. xy)$ because in $yx$ the free variable $x$ is replaced with $\lambda y. xy$.

Summing up, the correct $\beta$-reduction in your example is
$$
(\lambda x.yx)(\lambda y.xy) \to_\beta y(\lambda y. xy)
$$

Comment: That's what I originally got but https://lambdacalc.io/ gave me answer of yx.

Comment: @LoganLee - I guess you found a bug in [lambdacalc.io](https://lambdacalc.io/). You should contact the responsible for that project to report the bug.